# How do I use the image for table border for email?

Tags: html, css

I have an issue implementing `border-image` property for email HTML. Many clients still don't support css3 and this won't work. What are other solutions for that?

That's what I want to see as a result:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please ask an actual question that is not too broad. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tried to do image-border, but outlook and some other clients ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

From what i get, you want to implement border-image property for a particular div.

border-image follows the below syntax :-

> **border-image:** source slice width outset repeat|initial|inherit;

[image]

You can refer the following [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image) for more details. Also, it would be much better to answer if you share some code.